# IE6 compatibility. Page works fine everywhere but in IE6

Tags: javascript, css, html, internet-explorer-6

I have pretty much the same markup for all pages of the website, and most of them are done via php includes (in other words, the largest chunk of the code is the same throughout all pages).

All pages but one (dynamically generated) work as intended in all browsers including ie6.

The one page (for example, http://mincovlaw.com/doc/euro-excellence) works as intended in FF3.6, Chrome, Safari (including on iPhone) and IE7.

In IE6, it seems that there is some problem with the `<DIV>`s. I thought it had to do with the floating menu, but even if I remove the code completely, the DIVs are still not displayed correctly.

If you click on About or pretty much any other page of the website in IE6, the same structure of the DIVs works fine.

I do want the website to work in IE6. Please help me figure out why it behaves like this on this page.

To make things clearer, the three problems I am referring to in IE6 are:

1. The floating Bookmarks menu ends up in the right hand corner of the "paper", not in the right hand corner of the window, as it should.
2. Consequently, when I drag the bookmarks menu, the coordinates are all screwed up.
3. If you compare the page to, for example, Services in IE6, you will notice that on the Services page, the paper width is the same in the middle and on top and on the bottom, whereas it is slightly wider on the court decision page that I gave you the link for.

PS I know the code has many problems with validation, most of which have to do with `ul`'s not having corresponding `li`'s. This is currently by design.

IMPORTANT UPDATE!!! I have just discovered something. It seems that the problem #3 somehow is related to two lines in the css, namely:

```
text-align:justify;
```

for `p` and `.indented`

Can someone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: The real question is why you are still checking compatibility in IE6

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need help fixing the broken layout in IE6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582213/need-help-fixing-the-broken-layout-in-ie6)

Answer (score 3):

You should use the [HTML validation service](http://validator.w3.org/) to [validate your page](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://mincovlaw.com/doc/euro-excellence&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).

There are plenty of things that the validation complains about. Some things should not be a problem, like obsolete tags like `center` and `u`, and problems when the service tries to validate the Javascript code, but there are some actual errors in the code, like some `ul` tags that are not closed, and `ul` tags that contain `p` elements instead of `li` elements.

Comment: I did the validation, and saw these errors. it was my conscious decision to still use `UL` without `li` at this point (which I might reconsider in the future), but even when i remove ALL `ul`s from the local file here, it STILL shows up wrong. It appears that the when the validation complains about JS code _is_ in fact causing the problem with closing of `<div>`s. If only I could figure out why it works in every browser but IE6, i'd be happy

Comment: @Uno Mein Ame: You also have double `ul` tags in some places, where you should remove one of them in any case. If the Javascript is causing the problem, you can use `fromCharCode` to create string to avoid having `<` and `>` in the code, like `String.fromCharCode(60,98,62)` instead of `"<b>"`.

Comment: Now I figured something even crazier. I use the same HTML, JS and PHP to generate many pages. For some reason, http://mincovlaw.com/doc/udrp_policy is broken, while http://mincovlaw.com/doc/udrp_wipo_rules is fine. Can you please help me figure out the difference between the interpretation in these two?

Comment: You're using a strict doctype, but then using `ul`s and `li`s non-semantically? I'm amazed the page works at all.  Lists are your friends, but you have to treat them properly: all the javscript and css in the world can't fix broken basic markup.

Comment: i use `ul`s only to indent normal paragraphs to the right, not to create actual lists. I tried this with a simple `div` but then when the text gets copied in WinWord without formatting, all indentation is lost, which is unacceptable for my purposes.

Comment: @UnoMeinAme, the only mystery is why you think it's acceptable to use stray `<ul>` tags simply to indent paragraphs and then wonder why your page is broken in a ten-year-old browser.

Comment: @Sparky672, it is very simple. To me, functionality is more important than correctness and standards, and if stray `<ul>` tags is the only way to achieve it, then I'm going to do it that way. I know of no other way to keep indentation with no bullet points than to have these stray `<ul>` tags. As for IE6, the only reason I want to keep support for it is because I still use it myself.

Comment: @UnoMeinAme, **Standards are most important because there is no consistent functionality without standards**.  But I don't have to convince you of this since you're experiencing this big IE 6 "mystery" first hand.  ([learn how to indent a paragraph using `text-indent`.](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/indent.en.html))

Comment: @sparky672, when I refer to indentation, i don't mean css indentaion, i mean indentation in the resulting winword file, if you copy a bunch of paragraphs from your browser. I know several ways to display the same thing in a way that would be more coherent with the standards, but then when i'd copy it to clipboard and into word, all of that formatting would be gone. This is PRECISELY why I had to code it the way I did.